# Want to only show date not time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

My problem is the row, I want it to only show the date and not the time.

VOS.object_status_date returns dates like this:
2019-06-17 12:05:41.000
Im trying to get the time away and only keep the date

```
SELECT  
        PRO.process_no AS 'Job',
        PRO.process_name AS 'Name',  
        OBJ.object_no AS 'Object no', 
        OBW.work_type_no AS 'Worktype NO',
        OTY.object_type_no AS 'Object type',
        VOS.object_status_type_no AS 'Status NO', 
        VOS.object_status_date  AS 'Status date'    
        FROM [dbo].[PROCESS] PRO
            JOIN [dbo].[OBJECT_WORK] OBW ON PRO.process_id = OBW.process_id_job
            JOIN [dbo].[OBJECT] OBJ ON OBW.object_id = OBJ.object_id
            JOIN [dbo].[OBJECT_TYPE] OTY ON OBJ.object_type_id = OTY.object_type_id
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[V_OBJECT_STATUS_CURRENT] VOS ON OBJ.object_id = VOS.object_id 


        WHERE
    OBW.work_type_no in ('LL1','LN1')
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: 2019-06-17 12:05:41.000.  this is what VOS.object_status_date  AS 'Status date'    gives me. i want the time gone

Comment: Please [edit] any addition information into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the resulting value to be of DATE datatype you can use [CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (or CAST).

```
CONVERT(DATE, VOS.object_status_date)  AS 'Status date'
```

If you want a string and have SQL Server 2016 or higher you could use [FORMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
FORMAT(VOS.object_status_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US') as 'Status date'
```